# Guava file caching

Tags: java, android, caching, guava

I'm using Guava in my Android application for image loading and caching theyr filenames.

Here is my cache:

```
private static final LoadingCache<String, String> imageCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .softValues()
    .initialCapacity(3000)
    .maximumSize(3000)
    .concurrencyLevel(12)
    .expireAfterAccess(IMAGE_EXPIRATION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String load(String key) throws Exception {
            Log.d(TAG, "load " + key);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            final File imageFile = new File(cacheDir, "http---com-jWs-jpg");

            return imageFile.getPath();
        }
    });
```

And using:

```
String filename = imageCache.get(imageUrl);
Log.e(TAG, ">>> i:cache size :"+ imageCache.size() +":"+ imageCache.stats() +":"+ imageCache.asMap());
return Drawable.createFromPath(filename);
```

My problem is: there is 12 unique URLs in my list, but I have missCount count too large:

```
i:cache size :6:CacheStats{hitCount=36, missCount=48, loadSuccessCount=48, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=46569827...)
```

When I'm returning simple string (like file path or simply empty string), I have only 12 misses, and other `get` are the hits. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This code looks fine.  Are you sure that it's not expiring for normal reasons?

Comment: public static final int IMAGE_EXPIRATION_TIMEOUT = 7200; - I think, it's too much to expire in several seconds

Comment: The timeout is in milliseconds -- that's seven seconds -- and if you're using a lot of memory, `softValues` might be getting the entries GC'd.  Try adding a RemovalListener that logs the evictions and the reasons.

Comment: expireAfterAccess(IMAGE_EXPIRATION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS) - I've specified timeout in seconds o_O And when I'm trying to increase it, nothing happens

Comment: Wait.  Right.  Duh, sorry.  Still, use a `RemovalListener` to see if evictions are taking place and why.

Comment: THere is COLLECTED cause. It's because of garbage collector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, got it.

`.softValues()` was the cause, my values was COLLECTED by garbage collector. When I commented this, everything now works fine.

Comment: Three different expiration strategies at the same time is a bit excessive, anyway. (You expend additional memory per-entry with each one.)